# run only single thread in the method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a application in Spring MVC. In controller, user can run process(has button). Process working for one hour ( name it "longProces") .
So I want to run this method "longProces" in other thread.

When "longProces" is running, other user (when he want to run "longProces") should get message: "this process is running" and his thread is killed (not waiting for it turn).

What can I do this? Any idea?

Thank for answer

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some code sample .But in general you can have some kind of flag that is turned on when process starts to run and turned off when process ends  now before calling for start of the process you will check this flag .In addition i suggest to put the flag test  and start of the process in synchronized block to avoid  race condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ExecutorService instead of Executor.

Submit the task in executor service and maintain Future references say in some list or map.
`ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future future = threadExecutor.submit(new Task());
//submit the future in collection`

on every new request you can check already submitted task and there status if completed-

```
 //retrieve future instance from collection
 if(future.isDone()){ 
      //accept new request
 }
 else "process already running"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Priya Singh. But where I should define a ExecuteService and Future? Now, when I define Future class, second thread waiting for his time and then execute "longProces" when first thread finished own work. I want "kill" second thread when first is running at the time

Comment: You can create one singleton bean for ExecutorService  I.e.  TaskExecutor.  You need not to define future class its provided by JDK. If you have specific requirement that only one task should be running then you can keep instance variable reference for Future or if you want to store one task against one user then you can use map to store it.  I hope I am able to explain it properly.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a design based question.

For this scenario, my straight forward solution is - maintain this long process  status in database or any other persistence layer so that you can implement logic for every request first check is there any long process is active or not in the persistence. Based on this condition you can decide you flow.

One more critical point is, persistence layer approach would be the right solution to handle the multiple user request with one common shared process.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my sniped code:

```
@RequestMapping("/generate")
public String generate(HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
    String communique; = "The process is launching";

    Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
            generatorService.runLongProces();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    Executor tasExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    try{
    tasExecutor.execute(runnable);

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
     communique = "The process is failed";
    }

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);

    model.addAttribute("communique", communique);

    return "institutions/download";
}
```

I thought I set one thread in the constructor.

Maybe I should create a singleton bean for Spring TaskExecutor ?